# Where does macOS Big Sur store profile pics?

Tags: macos

I've been trying to find the location of a profile picture I've taken for a while now. I took the picture as I was setting my profile so it hasn't been saved to the Photos directory.

I tried looking for articles that can help but those are all for older versions of macOS.

Comment: I tried looking around and there's quite a few places it could potentially be, but this command worked to obtain my user profile picture that was saved to the desktop. Just enter the following command in terminal `dscl . -read /Users/john JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/pic.jpg` and it should paste the profile pic that you assigned in **Users & Groups settings** for your user account. NOTE: Where it says `john` in the command, change it your user account name, i.e. if your user account is `max` then enter `dscl . -read /Users/max JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > ~/Desktop/pic.jpg`

Comment: @AVelj
Why not make it an answer?  Why a comment?

Comment: @Redarm didn't have time to make a proper answer that would require me to format it correctly and such.

Comment: @AVelj I would have thought the community formats it for you, if you don't have the time or inclination.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to search for it in Terminal (one can find Terminal via Spotlight, or in `/Utilities`):

```
sudo find / -name "AAProfilePicture*" 2>/dev/null
```

Various places come up with the profile picture, e.g. a couple here:

```
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SetupAssistant
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.systempreferences
```

Once found, the search (`find`) can be interrupted with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> / or <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

**Another option:**

**Directory Utility** (to be found via Spotlight, or here: `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app`) also shows the user's picture under the "Directory Editor" tab with the user selected and it can be copied from there.  You may have to authenticate first.