# Where does Mac store photos that show up as suggestions for AppleID profile photos (Ventura 13.3.1)?

Tags: photos, apple-id

EDITED:

This is driving me nuts!

Where does Mac store photos that show up as suggestions for AppleID profile photo (photo on the top-right of the attached screenshot)?

I am running the latest macOS - Ventura 13.3.1

All the threads that I've found so far talk about finding the actual profile pictures, not the pictures that show as available to be used as a profile picture...

Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on what's not working for you in these "similar threads"? E.g. this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444618/where-does-macos-big-sur-store-profile-pics/444704#444704

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting back to me!  And apologies, I should have been more precise with my question -- I am looking for a location where the photo available in the "Photos" section is located -- as shown on the screenshot that I attached.  Not so much the profile picture itself (although I assumed they would be in the same location).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the Mac store account pictures?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44956/where-does-the-mac-store-account-pictures)

Comment: It’s stored within the directory service database.  See the linked dupe.  Even if you try to extract it, you’ll get a 250x250 image.  It’s not a high rez image of your original.  It’s a small thumbnail with relatively low quality.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me the current profile picture that I have currently active (so the one on the "left" on the screenshot I posted).  What I am after though is the picture on the "top right" of the screenshot, i.e. the picture available to select as a profile picture, under the "Photos" section (as seen on the screenshot).

Comment: Also directories service database.  It’s what is in that cache.  Also a 250x250 image and not the original.

Comment: Not sure if I am daft (quite possible) and doing something wrong, but I am only finding actual profile pictures, but not the picture that is actually shown as an option to pick from when selecting a profile photo.

Comment: Well that could simply be a suggestion from the People album that had detected that same person as on the current picture.

Comment: @tullman Thanks for clarifying.  Maybe you should add that info to your question, i.e. you are after the image within the Photos.app library.  So are you looking for a way to find that image within Photos?  Or is your question already answered by pointing you towards Photos and its library of images?

Comment: I have no idea if the image that I am after is within the Photos.app library...  On the screenshot that I attached it does show under the Photos tab of the 'pick you new AppleID profile picture' window, but I cannot find it anywhere within the actual Photos app.  It also weird that none of the other Photos.app pictures would show here as suggestions.  Only this one...

Comment: @tullman This feature has long been a work in progress and hasn't worked properly for me for yonks, with Apple trying to be either too helpful or clever on one hand (very limited face suggestions) and less than helpful (no resizing with a "People" album showing only first names, limited choices) on the other. At the moment I get only generic jpg images in Big Sur and my whole Photos library in Ventura. What you are seeing should really appear at the top of "Suggestions" in my opinion, with the whole Photos library showing with your selection. Sorry, but I have no answer.